# Getting "A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll" when updating with the code

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, updating

My `OCCUPIED`-column is `Boolean` and I would like the room status to change, so that it wont appear on the list of free rooms.

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    dataFile = "C:\Users\MAI KUDA\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\HOTEL MANAGMENT\HOTEL MANAGMENT\bin\Debug\MY HOTEL.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim str As String
    str = "update [ROOMS] set [OCCUPIED]=?status, [occupied by]=?name Where [ROOM] = ?room  "
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?status", True)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?name", Form3.NAMETextBox.Text And Form3.SURNAMETextBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?room", ROOMTextBox.Text)

    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()
        MsgBox("done")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("error")
    End Try

    Form3.ROOMTextBox.Text = ROOMTextBox.Text
    Me.Validate()
    Me.ROOMSBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.MY_HOTELDataSet)
    Me.Hide()
    Form3.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: Not 100% sure if this is causing the exception, but `Form3.NAMETextBox.Text And Form3.SURNAMETextBox.Text` is not concatenating the both strings. It should rather be `Form3.NAMETextBox.Text & Form3.SURNAMETextBox.Text`. What's the content of the both textboxes?

Comment: Be sure to include the exception message when you encounter an error you have a question about. Chances are the message, or the message of the inner exception, spells out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.

1. The Ado.NET OleDB provider, used for ms access, uses `?` as parameter place holders. They are not named so drop the name entirely and only use the question mark. Be sure the order of the parameters matches the order they appear in the statement.
2. When concatenating strings in vb use `&` and not the word `AND` which is for combining booleans. I added a space between the name parts, remove it if this is not your intention.
3. Not applicable to the error but I strongly suggest using [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) blocks to ensure your connections are closed / disposed.

Updated relevant code:

```
str = "update [ROOMS] set [OCCUPIED] = ?, [occupied by]= ? Where [ROOM] = ?"
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
' here the name no longer matters so keep it or drop it up to you as long as the order matches the order in the statement.
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?status", True)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?name", Form3.NAMETextBox.Text  & " " & Form3.SURNAMETextBox.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?room", ROOMTextBox.Text)
```